# Why does an exponential function have two forms?

Tags: exponential-function

I saw two different forms for an exponential function which are:

> - $f(x)=a^x$

and

> - $f(x)=a \cdot b^x$ where $a$ is the initial value

**Are the rules and cases the same in both forms such as:**

- It is always greater than 0, and never crosses the x-axis
- It always intersects the y-axis at y=1 ... in other words it passes through (0,1)
- At x=1, f(x)=a ... in other words it passes through (1,a)
- It is an Injective (one-to-one) function
- Its Range is the Positive Real Numbers: (0, +∞)

and so on.

Comment: "... where $a$ is the initial value" looks like a big hint for whether or not the second condition holds in both cases.

Comment: They are not the same, the second one is a general form of the first one (which is the particular case where the multiplying factor is $1$). Also, the second and third "rules" are not true for the second form: the intersection is at $y=a$ and $f(1)=a\,b$

Comment: Additional note: You can always write $a \times b^x = b^{\log_b{a}} b^x = b^{x+\log_b{a}}$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Also the third condition suffers a change of scale.